# Redirect stdout on Unix

Tags: c++, c, unix, stdout

I'm doing a project using the SDL library.

I noticed that stdout and stderr were redirected to 2 files : stdout.txt and stderr.txt.

I managed to redirect the streams back on a Windows platform, but I just can't do it for Unix platforms...

```
void redirectSDLStreams () {
    #ifdef _WIN32
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    #elifdef __unix__ // Not sure about it tho
    // Code for Unix
    #endif
}
```

I tried :

```
printf("Ok from stdout\n") // Prints something
freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);
printf("Ok from /dev/tty\n") // Prints nothing
```

and :

```
printf("Ok from stdout\n") // Prints something
freopen("/dev/stdout", "w", stdout);
printf("Ok from /dev/stdout\n") // Prints nothing
```

But both failed on Fedora 17...

Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);` is ok. However, SDL never reopened stdout/stderr on linux.

SDL 1.2 did that on windows and, depending on configuration, on mac os. SDL2 dropped that and now never redirects output.